# 2FA / Apple, using Authy

Tags: ios, authentication, two-factor-authentication

Here is a question about two-factor-authentication on Apple.

I use 2FA when logging into my Apple Developer account, receiving the verification code on some device.
Beside I use the Authy app (for 2FA) to log into some other service.

The question is: could I use the same Authy app when logging in to my Apple Developer account?

If the answer is YES, how do I set this up?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s not about programming. The answer to your question is no, because Authy is a proprietary service that differs from what Apple’s 2FA is using.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/343309/ability-to-add-non-sms-non-apple-2fa-to-an-apple-id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authy developer evangelist here.

As far as I know, and I've set it up this way, Apple rely on a proprietary 2FA implementation that uses macOS or iOS, so you are not able to use Authy to generate a verification code.